# Xamarin Android App - Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

I was hoping some one could help me with this. I have been scouring the internet for an answer, but one is not revealing itself to me. I am getting this error when trying to include the Nuget Package "Nutrionix" in an Android App Project within Xamarin. "Microsoft.Http.Net" is a dependency of "Nutritionix" and I have had troubles adding this package before, but now I am getting this error. Please help! Thanks in advance..

Here is the super long error message if anyone can make sense of it...

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets: Error: Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono for Android profile?
File name: 'System.Web.dll'
  at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference, Mono.Cecil.ReaderParameters parameters) <0x3cdfd18 + 0x00423> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tuner.DirectoryAssemblyResolver.Resolve (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyNameReference reference) <0x3d2fbb0 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences (ICollection`1 assemblies, Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly, Boolean topLevel) <0x3d2f260 + 0x0046b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute () <0x3d2e688 + 0x00577> in <filename unknown>:0  (ProteinTracker)
```